# Minimum of exponential distribution

Tags: pr.probability, expectation

Consider $n$ independent random variables $_\sim\exp(_)$ for $I=1\ldots,n$. Let $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Of course, the minimum of these exponential distributions has distribution:
$X=\min_{i}{X_i}\sim\exp(\lambda)$.

I was told that $X_i$ is the minimum variable with probability  $\lambda_i/\lambda$. How do we know this? What's the proof?

Comment: Looks like homework question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125556/minimum-of-exponential-distributions . But of course, who cares?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$Conditioning on $X_1$ and using the independence of the $X_j$'s, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X_1<X_2,\dots,X_n)
&=\int_0^\infty P(X_1\in dx)\,P(x<X_2,\dots,X_n) \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty dx\,\la_1 e^{-\la_1 x}\,P(x<X_2,\dots,X_n) \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty dx\,\la_1 e^{-\la_1 x}\,P(x<X_2)\cdots P(x<X_n) \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty dx\,\la_1 e^{-\la_1 x}\,e^{-\la_2 x}\cdots e^{-\la_n x} \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty dx\,\la_1 e^{-(\la_1+\cdots\la_n) x} \\ 
&=\frac{\la_1}{\la_1+\cdots+\la_n}. 
\end{aligned}$$
Similarly,
$$P(X_i<X_1,\dots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\dots,X_n)
=\frac{\la_i}{\la_1+\cdots+\la_n} 
$$
for all $i=1,\dots,n$.